# How to access subviews in nested UIScrollViews

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimageview, subview

I was having trouble getting a UIScrollView with multiple UIImageView subviews to zoom properly so I tried using a UIScrollView with multiple UIScrollView subviews inside of it and a UIImageView inside of each of those. That way one UIScrollView can only scroll and the other can only zoom.

My question is: How can I access subviews of a subview. I know that normally I can access subviews using `[scrollView viewWithTag:tagInt];` for example, but I can't seem to access the subviews of a subview using `[[scrollView viewWithTag:tagInt] viewWithTag:tagInt2];` since viewWithTag only returns a single UIView and not all of it's subviews.

I could always give each subview a unique tag and access them that way, but that doesn't seem to be the most elegant solution.

What is the best way to access a subView and then get to the subView's subview (ie: access my UIScrollView used for zooming which is a subview of my main view, and then access it's subView UIImageView)?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't feel comfortable subclassing for now, you'd have to assign tags to the UIScrollViews containing images. You'd then have to do what the BobC suggested with a little more work.

```
for (UIView *subview in [myScrollView subviews])
{
   //check if the current subview is one of the UIScrollViews
   if (subview.tag > 100)
        //do something with the UIScrollView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way to do this would be to subclass `UIScrollView`, give it a `UIImageView` property. That way, you could access this `UIImageView` with something like:

```
MyScrollView *myScrollView = (MyScrollView *)[scrollView viewWithTag:tagInt];
UIImageView *imageView = myScrollView.imageView;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That sounds like a nice solution but unfortunately subclassing is a bit over my head right now. Is there any simpler method to access all subviews of a subview?

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of subviews of any UIView using subviews property.

```
for(UIView *subview in [myScrollView subviews]) {
     // do anything with your subview here. 
}
```